# How to speed up the minification process of UglifyJS 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, uglifyjs

I am using [UglifyJS 2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) to concatenate and minify a bunch of JavaScript files (not too much, around 5 to 10). This process is run from within Node.js by using the default settings of UglifyJS 2.

The files are basically Require.js, jQuery, Backbone.js, Backbone.js Marionette, Moment.js, and some additional (smaller) helper files, all in the uncompressed (i.e. development) versions.

The problem is that this process nearly takes 10 seconds.

If I disable minification completely by handing over

```
{ compress: false }
```

as an option, it's a lot faster, but it still takes around 2 seconds.

Question #1: Is it usual that UglifyJS 2 takes *that* long even for a few files? Or am I most probably doing something wrong?

Question #2: How can I speed up this process, without disabling all the useful options of UglifyJS 2?

Comment: We have no clue about the size of your files. I have a JS project that takes about 7-8 seconds to compress. The project is about 7 files, each of them is about 400-500 lines.

Comment: I've updated my question, but your comment already points out that taking multiple seconds seems to be normal for my scenario. Thanks :-)!

Comment: You are NOT minifying these files upon every request, are you?

Comment: No, I don't. It gets done one time at startup, and I am thinking about moving it to build time.

Comment: @GoloRoden Good idea. Always minify while you're building.

Comment: Well ... the drawback is that you can not exchange a single file while the application is running, and minifying happens in-place at runtime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not uncommon that minifiers take a few seconds to compress multiple large files. 8-12 seconds is okay in your case (multiple large libraries).

However, I recommend not to compress these libraries yourself. Most of them have a team of developers behind them who really know what they're doing, I recommend downloading the minified versions from the source and do as simple as

```
copy *.min.js allLibraries.js
```

or

```
cp *.min.js allLibraries.js
```

**Note:** Make sure you concatenate in the correct order, this usually means `The main libraries -> The plugins -> Your code`.

As for speeding up, other than disabling the cool features like the strong compression, there's nothing much you can do.

Comment: So this means, get the minified versions, compress only my own files using a tool such as Uglify JS, and then concat them, right?

Comment: Well, to be honest, this is what _I_ do. There might be some opinions out there that says otherwise.

Comment: Hey downvoter, would please help me improve my answer? Please let me know what I got wrong so I can correct it.

Comment: I agree, this would be the best way to speed it up. I see no reason to downvote this. @GoloRoden Since you are already using node.js and uglifyjs, you might want to look into using [Gurnt](http://gruntjs.com/). It has support built in for concatenating files, running uglify on them and it will also lint them with [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint). There are also a [ton of other pre-built tasks](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/gruntplugin) you can install too.

Comment: I'm actually already using Grunt, and this would definitely be *THE* tool to run such a task :-)

Answer (score 18):

If you set the compress unused option to false, it should speed it up a bit.  I got mine from 11sec to 5.5sec with just that.

```
   { 
       compress: {
           unused: false
       }
   }
```

Less than a 2k difference with it off.

Comment: Nice find, mine went from 28s to 8s.  Reviewing how much file size was saved, it saved me about 1kb (on a roughly 1.3MB file) to remove unused code (I would have expected much larger).  I'll take the 20s speed improvement!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The speed improvement is huge

Comment: @woens This should only work on a case by case basis. As in, the difference can be larger than 1kb depending on how many libraries you need to include in your project.

Comment: went from 25 seconds to 9 seconds. Victory!